# I need someone to fix this small script,it almost works! images appear on view/scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi guys I'm having some trouble with this script!

I have a galerie of images with an opacity set to 0 in my css, and I'd like those images to appear when scrolling down(on view) In this script I have set it so they appear when they are 50% of the image height but they appear at 100% I don't know why..

```
<script>    

    function isScrolledIntoView(elem, percent_image_before_appearing){
    if(typeof percent_image_before_appearing == "undefined") percent_image_before_appearing = 0;

    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    var break_point = elemTop + (percent_image_before_appearing/100) * $(elem).width();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && ( (break_point) >= docViewTop));
}
    function changeOpacity(){
    $("img").each(function(){
    var img = $(this);

        if (isScrolledIntoView(this,50)){
            img.css("opacity","1.0");
        }
    });
}

$(function(){

    changeOpacity();
    $(window).scroll(changeOpacity);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason

```
 var break_point = elemTop + (percent_image_before_appearing/100) * $(elem).width();
```

uses `.width()` instead of `.height()`?

More importantly, you have

```
elemBottom <= docViewBottom
```

Which is asking, is the element bottom less than the docViewBottom. In other words, is the bottom of the image higher than the bottom of the window. In other words again, is it in view completely.

I suspect you actually want

```
break_point <= docViewBottom
```

which checks if the breakpoint (the 50% point) is visible.

Comment: There was no reason it was my mistake! I changed it for .height and corrected ( break_point <= docViewBottom ) And it works perfectly thank you mate :)